# Image and video capture like Snapchat/Instagram stories

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, snapchat

I have read online that snapchat and instagram have a different approach to capturing video as opposed to using the camera APIs in Android, this allows them to add filters/stickers etc to the captured content.

Can anyone advise on ways to approach this? potential libraries, android classes etc.

Comment: Why do you ask **us** how **they** do it? Why don't you ask **them**?

Comment: @VladMatvienko If I could ask them and get reply, I would. There is no point in commenting if you will provide zero help, if you dont know, dont comment. thanks

Comment: Sorry, but looks like you didn't read through the rules of SO when accepted them. Please read, and you will understand that the goal of SO is **not to help you**, but to collect a database of solutions. And while your question is off-topic, it harms SO, and I'm welcome to do whatever I can (including commenting) to make it on-topic. So please reformat your question not to look like *how did they do it*, but to state **what exactly you want to know** at least because not everybody is using instagram and snapchat.

Comment: @VladMatvienko You dont know how to do it, I understand.

Comment: please read the SO rules before offending me. I know how to do that, but nobody is welcome to answer questions that harm SO. And I will answer only once the question is on-topic and correct.

Comment: I'm interested in this question too. Days of searching doesn't give me a positive result. And the deal even isn't the adding filters/stickers, but the fine-working image and video capture. Camera 2 API is a nightmare, it has a lot of bugs and problems with the performance. I think Instagram and Snapchat use opencv,  c/c++ since low-level language is much faster than java. But if you have no practice in c/c++ programming, it will be a challenge to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if they have a different method of *capturing* the media, but they're surely doing a lot more than simply using a Video/ImageView to render it once it's captured.

I've worked on the problem of adding filters/stickers to photos and videos before. The best solution I came up with was to use a two-stage approach.

A single stage approach would be to capture media, then apply a filter to the media, and then preview that processed media. This doesn't work as the filtering process is slow to process a whole video.

A two stage approach involves a real-time preview before actually applying the filter.

If you're smart about it, things like moving stickers around and drawing on an image can simply be inputs into the preview filter, which is then made concrete when the user saves the media.

If you're interested in seeing how this works, I have published an open source library that demonstrates how to do this: https://github.com/isaac-udy/Kfilter